# Django views filter by date startswith

Tags: python, django

I have a model label like this:

```
date_realization = models.DateField(_('Realised in'),
                                     default=timezone.now)
```

Then an url like this :

```
    url(r'^date/(?P<daterealization>[\w\.@+-]+)/$', DateEntriesView.as_view(), name='articles-date'),
```

When I am sending the url, it's like this:

> www.mondomaine.com/articles/date/2016-01

And my date_realization field is like this :

> 2016-01-13

And **what I want to do is to return all articles that have this date.**

So I tried what I did for categories, but the behaviour is a bit different here.
This is what I tried to do :

```
class DateEntriesView(ContextSourcesMixin, BaseArticleView, BaseArticleListView):
model = Article
context_object_name = 'article_list'
template_name = 'base_templates/template_press.html'
_date_realization = None
paginate_by = None
view_url_name = 'djangocms_press:articles-date'

def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # submit object to cms toolbar to get correct language switcher behavior
    if hasattr(self.request, 'toolbar'):
        self.request.toolbar.set_object(self.date_realization)
    return super(DateEntriesView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

@property
def date_realization(self):
    if not self._date_realization:
        try:
            date_realization_qs = Article.objects.active_translations(
                get_language(),
                date_realization__startswith=self.kwargs['daterealization']
            )

            self._date_realization = date_realization_qs.latest('pk')
        except Article.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("Article does not exist for this site")
    return self._date_realization

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(DateEntriesView, self).get_queryset()
    if 'date_realization' in self.kwargs:
        qs = qs.filter(date_realization__pk=self.date_realization.pk)
    return qs

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['date_realization'] = self.date_realization
    return super(DateEntriesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

But I got this exception message:

> Exception Type: FieldError at /en/press/date/2016-01/
>
> Exception Value: Relation fields do not support nested lookups

Thus, I feel stuck.

EDIT:

Well, the model Article is very long,

```
@version_controlled_content
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Article(ModelMeta, TranslatableModel):
taints_cache = True

"""
Press article element,
"""
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
date_realization = models.DateField(_('Realised in'),
                                     default=timezone.now)
image = FilerImageField(verbose_name=_('Featured image'), blank=True,
                             null=True,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             related_name='image_press_article',
                             help_text=_('Set if the article will be featured'))

sources = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleSource, verbose_name=_('Source'),
                                    blank=False, null=True, related_name='sources_press_article')

regions = models.ManyToManyField(Country, verbose_name=_('Country of the article'),
                                 blank=True, null=True,
                                 related_name='regions_press_article')

global_regions = models.BooleanField('Global', default=False)

featureArticle = models.BooleanField(_('Feature'), help_text=_('Feature this article'), default=False)

sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, verbose_name=_('Sites'), blank=True,
                                                    null=True,
                                                    help_text=_('Select sites in which show the project.'))

article_url = models.CharField(_('Article Url'), max_length=310, blank=False,
                                   help_text=_('Use to link to the original source'))

countries_displayed_in = models.ManyToManyField(
    Country,
    verbose_name=_('Countries displayed in'),
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    related_name='displayed_in_press_article',
    help_text='Select the countries in which this project will be visible.'
    'If not selected, the project will be visible in all countries otherwise it will be'
    'visible only for users that are located in the countries selected')

translations = TranslatedFields(
    title=models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=510),
    slug=models.SlugField(_('slug'), blank=False, db_index=True, max_length=300),
    description=HTMLField(_('article description if featured'), default='', blank=True,
                          configuration='HTMLFIELD_CKEDITOR_SETTINGS_CONTENT'),

    meta_description=models.TextField(verbose_name=_('article meta description'),
                                      blank=True, default=''),
    meta_keywords=models.TextField(verbose_name=_('article meta keywords'),
                                   blank=True, default=''),
    meta_title=models.CharField(verbose_name=_('article meta title'),
                                help_text=_('used in title tag and social sharing'),
                                max_length=255,
                                blank=True, default=''),
    meta={'unique_together': (('language_code', 'slug'),)}
)

objects = ProjectManager()

_metadata = {
    'title': 'get_title',
    'description': 'get_description',
    'keywords': 'get_keywords',
    'locale': None,
    'image': 'get_image_full_url',
    'published_time': 'date_created ',
    'modified_time': 'date_modified',
    # Handle the get_absolute_url in the view to have access to the request
    # and so, to the current_app namespace instance
    # 'url': 'get_absolute_url',
}

def country(self):
    return "\n".join(([p.name for p in self.regions.all()]))

def source(self):
    return "\n".join([p.name for p in self.sources.all()])

def get_title(self):
    title = self.safe_translation_getter('meta_title', any_language=True)
    if not title:
        title = self.safe_translation_getter('title', any_language=True)
    return title.strip()

def get_keywords(self):
    return self.safe_translation_getter('meta_keywords').strip().split(',')

def get_description(self):
    description = self.safe_translation_getter('meta_description', any_language=True)
    if not description:
        description = self.safe_translation_getter('description', any_language=True)
    return escape(strip_tags(description)).strip()

def get_image_full_url(self):
    if self.image:
        return self.image.url
    return ''

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('Press article')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Press articles')
    get_latest_by = 'date_realization'

def __str__(self):
    title = self.safe_translation_getter('title', any_language=True)
    return title if title is not None else '(not translated)'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    main_lang = self.get_current_language()
    for lang in self.get_available_languages():
        self.set_current_language(lang)
        if not self.slug and self.title:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    self.set_current_language(main_lang)
    self.save_translations()

def get_slug(self):
    return self.safe_translation_getter(
        'slug',
        language_code=get_language(),
        any_language=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd instead parse the date's month/year through the urlconf.

```
 url(r'^date/(?P<date_year>[0-9]+)-(?P<date_month>[0-9]+)/$', 
                     DateEntriesView.as_view(), name='articles-date'),
```

and then in your view :

```
date_realization_qs = Article.objects.active_translations(
                get_language(),
                date_realization__month=self.kwargs['date_month'],
                date_realization__year=self.kwargs['date_year']
            )
```

Keep in mind that if you try and call a key from `self.kwargs` that doesn't exist, you will get an error. Perhaps it's better to call `self.kwargs.get('date_month',datetime.date().month)` to have a default of current month if none supplied (as well as calling the same for year).

Comment: This is smart, I appreciate the url hint, I forget about it :)
But I still have the error : " Relation fields do not support nested lookups"
when I try those lines : date_realization__month=self.kwargs['date_month'],
                date_realization__year=self.kwargs['date_year']

Comment: Hmmm... that seems odd. I wonder if this is related to `get_language()` in some way. If you can post the `Articale` model definition and the code defining `get_language()` I might be able to help more. Full stacktrace too perhaps?

Comment: I just updated my first post.
get language is a django contrib: from django.utils.translation import get_language

Comment: oh, btw, when I try to add self.kwargs.get... I have this error :
`Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found`

Comment: Whatever you have named the year param for your request is what you are seeking, I was just showing an example; print out `*args` and  `**kwargs` to see the full dictionaries passed to the view

Comment: Yes, I found a solution by removing the check made in the try.
It's ugly but I had to act fast.